# Filename Numbering in Python

Tags: python

I want to put proper sequence no in my file using python. Its working partially not fully. Suppose in a particular folder there is 3 files. The sequence should Num1_.doc,Num2_.pdf,Num3_.doc. It's working fine.

But suppose a new file is coming on that folder, how it maintain the proper sequence.

My code is -

```
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Project\\')
print(os.getcwd())

for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_name = "Num" + str(count) + '_' + f_name
    new_name = f'{f_name}{f_ext}'
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Its generate Num1_.doc,Num2_.pdf,Num3_.doc etc.
Now new file is added on that folder. The sequence should  Num4_.doc. How to do it in python.

Comment: Read all file names in dir, rename new file to correct number ... if you are all in one script run you can use an internal counter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first get the maximum number already assigned from previous renamings, and then rename the remaining files starting from that number.

```
import os
import re

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Project\\')
print(os.getcwd())
# find max number in filenames, if already named
filenames = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir()]
filenames = filter(lambda f: f[:3] == "Num" and len(f) >= 4, filenames)
max_n_file = max(map(lambda f: int(re.search('^[0-9]*', f[3:]).group(0)), filenames), default=0) + 1
# apply same algorithm but rename only not-"Num_" files
for _, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if f_name[:3] != "Num":
        f_name = "Num" + str(max_n_file) + '_' + f_name
        new_name = f'{f_name}{f_ext}'
        os.rename(f, new_name)
        max_n_file += 1
```

Comment: Sorry.Its not working. Output looks - Num1_abc.pdf
Num2_Num1_xyz.pdf
Num3_Num2_abx.doc

Comment: edited it, check if it works now

Comment: Sorry its not working. My file name like - Num1_abc.pdf, Num2_fds.doc,Num3_aa.pdf. New file comes with abbb.pdf. But after running its gives me below results - 
Num1_abbb.pdf
Num2_Num1_abc.pdf
Num3_Num2_fds.doc
Num4_Num3_aa.pdf

Which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Find what the maximum number is out of the current files, then rename any new files with a number 1 higher

```
import os

current_max = 0
for i in os.listdir():

    # The number in this filename
    num = int(i[3:-5])
    if num > current_max:
        current_max = num

    # If the current_file has not been named yet
    if "Num_" not in i:
        #Rename by adding 1 to the current maximum number recorded
        os.rename(i, f"Num_{current_max+1}")
```

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6832/2884198031.py in <module>
      7 
      8     # The number in this filename
----> 9     num = int(i[3:-5])
     10     if num > current_max:
     11         current_max = num

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
Just one thing instead of Num_ I need Num1_,Num2_,Num3_ ...NumN_ etc.